# Crypto with Key & IV generator from a password and SALT in .NETMF

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, .net-micro-framework, .net-gadgeteer

I am implementing a .NET Micro Framework application and I have a code such as:

```
public static void Main()
{
    string data = "Here is some text to encrypt.";

    AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
    csp.GenerateKey();
    csp.GenerateIV();

    CryptoKey k = csp.Key;
    byte[] iv = csp.IV;

    byte[] key = k.ExportKey(true);

    AesCryptoServiceProvider csp2 = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] enc = AesEncrypt(UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data), key, iv);
    byte[] dec = AesDecrypt(enc, key, csp.IV);
    char[] c = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetChars(dec);
    string decodedStr = new string(c);
    Debug.Print("\n dec: " + decodedStr );
}

public static byte[] AesEncrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        csp.Key = CryptoKey.ImportKey(csp.Session, key,
        CryptoKey.KeyClass.Secret, CryptoKey.KeyType.AES, true);

        csp.IV = iv;
        using (ICryptoTransform encr = csp.CreateEncryptor())
        {
            return encr.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
    }
}
public static byte[] AesDecrypt(byte[] encryptedData, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider csp = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        csp.Key = CryptoKey.ImportKey(csp.Session, key,
        CryptoKey.KeyClass.Secret, CryptoKey.KeyType.AES, true);
        csp.IV = iv;
        using (ICryptoTransform decr = csp.CreateDecryptor())
        {

            return decr.TransformFinalBlock(encryptedData, 0, encryptedData.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

My gadgeteer (FEZ Hydra) will encrypt some text. It will **NOT** have internet connection, so it will output it via OLED display or sth. And I am going to decrypt it in .NET Framework PC.
Now I have 2 questions:

1- Unfortunately .NETMF 4.2 RTM (QFE2) does not have any functions which exist in .NET Framework such as `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` or `RandomNumberGenerator`. Therefore I could not find a way to derive Key&IV from a Password and SALT.

2- (assuming we solved question #1)I cannot use random Key and IV for every encryption/decryption since gadgeteer does not have internet connection in order to send the key&IV to my .NET Framework PC in a secure way. So I think an alternative solution: If I derive key & IV from a password & SALT, and both my gadgeteer(to encrypt) and PC(to decrypt) uses the same password & SALT, then I could handle it. Yes I am hearing the voices **Do not use same IV etc. for more than one encryption..** But my MUST is not to connect gadgeteer to wifi because of Cost and other issues. Under these circumstances, is this a secure way to do this or does it need way much improvement (such as public&private key implementation etc.)? And how?

I'll be glad for any advise, Thank You

Murat

Answer (score 0):

I have not used the .net Micro Framework. However, the api listing has a random number generator called [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh423389.aspx). Rfc2898DeriveBytes is just PBKDF2 implementation using Hmac-Sha1 and there exist a [KeyedHashAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh422676.aspx) class that suports HMAC-SHA1 (see algorithm [PBKDF2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) it's pretty simple).